# Column Source Ordering [ Zurb Foundation 5 ]

Tags: css, css-float, zurb-foundation-5

I am trying to get this layout working both on mobile as desktop. It is possible by duplicating a column and using show-for-small/large, but I'd like to achieve it only with using push/pull states or anything similar (so no repeating markup).

Medium/Large:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| column-A | column-B | column-C | column-D |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|                  column-E                 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Small:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|                  column-A                 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|                  column-B                 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|                  column-C                 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|                  column-E                 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|                  column-D                 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

This works for large, but obviously not for small. http://jsfiddle.net/2rmfas9r/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-12 large-3">A</div>
    <div class="columns small-12 large-3">B</div>
    <div class="columns small-12 large-3">C</div>
    <div class="columns small-12 large-3">D</div>
    <div class="columns small-12">E</div>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way, to achieve the desired layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Foundation source ordering, there's no way to do that without repeating your markup. It works only for columns on the same row.

Generally speaking, you can't do that with css, because a column must occupy its space and you don't know how much it is long.

If your `column-E` has a fixed height, you can put that on `position:absolute` and `bottom: 0`, and add a `padding-bottom` to the `.row`, equal to the `column-E`'s height.

if you can use Javascript, you can simply use `Foundation.utils.is_medium_up()` to check in wich viewport you are and then use jQuery `.deatch()` and `.append()` for `column-E` repositioning.

Comment: According to me, it's better to [repeat the column](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29122375/2641416) than use javascript, it's more visible what happening

Comment: I prefer clean code and dry style (don't repeat yourself).
In  my programmer life, I saw too many manteniance problems due to duplicate contents, made only to accomodate visual aspect needings.
So whenever I can, I prefer to avoid duplicate contents :)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I'd rather duplicate the content with JS instead of checking on screensizes making the performance go down, but I get where you're coming from. I'll mark this as the answer for now, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As you want to switch column E, you need to use the class **show-for-small** and **show-for-large**

```
<div class="row show-for-small-only">
    <div class="columns small-12">A</div>
    <div class="columns small-12">B</div>
    <div class="columns small-12">C</div>
    <div class="columns small-12">E</div>
    <div class="columns small-12">D</div>
</div>
<div class="row show-for-large-only">
    <div class="columns large-3">A</div>
    <div class="columns large-3">B</div>
    <div class="columns large-3">C</div>
    <div class="columns large-3">D</div>
    <div class="columns large-12">E</div>
</div>
```